# PowerBI - Need for Premium Capacity nodes for DirectQuery

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-datasource

All,

We plan to use DirectQuery against our On-Prem data sources. The infrastructure team is pushing us to get a P1 Premium Node. I understand that Premium Capacity is very much needed for Import Mode but for  DirectQuery mode what role does the Premium Capacity play given that data is in the data source and data processing such as sort,group happen in the data source itself?

Can someone please point me in the right direction.

Rajee

Comment: For example with P1 your report consumers doesn't need to have Power BI Pro license.

Comment: Licenses aside, how will DirectrQuery impact P1 nodes given that sort/group by, aggregating happens on the data source side itself. Cant I just leave the Self-Service Workspace in the Default mode (without any Premium Capability)?

Comment: Not every data operation if pushed to the database. Also rendering is always there. Also other workloads - paginated reports for example, AI, etc. The dedicated capacity gives you predictable performance by avoiding noisy neighbours on the shared infrastructure. But discuss this with your team. Ask them for their reasons.